# How can I get vertical lines left and right of an align with a linear system of equations?

Tags: tables, equations, align, amsmath, mathtools

I've tried to use the `align` environment for my work. But, I don't know how to get vertical lines either side of the equations. The picture shows my attempt, but, it uses the `tabular` environment and the lines aren't the same length.

```
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}

$\mathsf{-1x+5y}            $&$=$&      $\mathsf{6}$\\

$\mathsf{-3x-5y}            $&$=$&      $\mathsf{-4}$\\ \\

\end{tabular}
```

[image: tabular]

I can't go close to that result with the `align` environment.

Comment: Any motivation behind this need? Do you need the individual equations numbered, or the whole thing numbered?

Comment: Just remove the backslashes at the end of the second line.

Answer (score 4):

[`empheq`](//ctan.org/pkg/empheq) provides functionality for inserting content before (to the `left`) or after (to the `right`) of an `align`-like environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\left|,right=\right|]{align*}
  -1x + 5y &=  6 \\
  -3x - 5y &= -4
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple with the `systeme` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{sansmath} 

\begin{document}

\sansmath
\[ \sysdelim| |
\systeme{%
   -1x+5y=6,
    -3x-5y=-4\,} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the contents of the `tabular` environment are all math-y, I'd switch to an `array` environment to save myself from having to enter lots of `$` symbols. Since you seem to be interested in sans-serif math lettering, I'd load the `sansmath` package and run `\sansmath`, freeing me from having to inputs lots of `\mathsf` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for columns with binary and relational operators

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{| r @{}C@{} r @{}C@{} r|}
  -1x &+& 5y  &=&  6 \,\\
  -3x &-& 5y  &=& -4 
\end{array}$
   
\end{document}
```